# как создать правильно Factory Laravel 8 - для заполнения таблицы случайными данными?

Tags: laravel

есть у меня к примеру таблица reviews

```
id  bigint unsigned Автоматическое приращение           
name    varchar(255)    
email   varchar(255)    
rating  int 
description text
```

выполнил команду
php artisan make:factory ReviewFactory --model=Review

создался файл в Database\Factories\ReviewFactory

```
<?php

namespace Database\Factories;

use App\Models\Review;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\Factory;

class ReviewFactory extends Factory
{
    /**
     * The name of the factory's corresponding model.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $model = Review::class;

    /**
     * Define the model's default state.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function definition()
    {
        return [
            //Записал я сюда вот так 
            'name' => $this->faker->name,
            'email' => 'test.com',
            'rating' => 5,
            'description' => 'description',
        ];
    }
}


//Что еще нужно сделать чтобы заполнилось случайными отзывами к примеру 200 шт?
```

спасибо!

Comment: [прочтите](https://thisis-blog.ru/generaciya-nachalnyx-dannyx-v-laravel/) - всё коротко и по сути

Comment: Нужно создать ещё и `ReviewSeeder`. Документация: [Наполнение фиктивными данными](https://docs.rularavel.com/docs/8.x/seeding).